# replacing space with comma-space, except at end of line python

Tags: python, python-3.x

> 1 2 3 4 5 6
>
> 9 9 9 9 9 9
>
> The output I am getting with my code:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
>
> 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9,
>
> The output I want:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
>
> 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as f, open('file2.txt', 'w') as x:
    for line in f:
        x.write(line.replace(" ", ", "))
```

the code I wrote is adding a comma at the end of 6 as well. Which is not what I want. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Sounds like you have trailing spaces.  Do `x.write(line.strip().replace(" ", ", "))`, maybe?

Comment: @Samwise Thanks for the quick reply. The issue is that what you're code does is that it will combine all the other lines into one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as f, open('file2.txt', 'w') as x:
    for line in f:
    x.write(", ".join(line.strip().split(" "))+'\n')
```

Comment: But what if the file had multiple lines. And I wanted to add commas to all these lines except at the end.

Comment: @itsyoyo did you even try this code?  It should work

Comment: The '/n' at the end of each line caused some problem. I have updated my code. Please try and tell me if it works

Comment: @IoaTzimas It now works with the updated code. Thank you!